# How to get the src attribute of the element by its id in visual basic 6

Tags: vb6, webbrowser-control

I have a page with the following HTML content:

```
<img src="image.png" id="image">
```

and in my VB6 code I have a WebBrowser control which loads up that page, and now I want to fetch the `src` attribute of the image, and I tried this:

```
Dim image
image = WebBrowser1.Document.getElementById("image")

dim image_src as String
image_src = image.src
```

But I get the error `Invalid qualifier`. I debuged the `image` variable after the `getElementById` function call and I get: `[object]`.

So, how can I get the `src` attribute of the image?

edit:

The thing that worked in the end was:

```
image = WebBrowser1.Document.getElementById("image").src
```

but to me, this doesn't make any sense, if this upper code works (just tested it), how come the one I tried first doesn't? I would kindly appreciate someone who can provide the explanation to this.

Comment: Have you verified the HTML has only one element with `id="image"`?  Or this being VB6 that there are no elements with `name="image"` as well.

Comment: It has been a while... quick search I am seeing a lot of `.getElementById('foo').getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src;` which doesn't make much sense to me but might be worth pursuing.  Also, just in case, try adding `name="image"` to that HTML element, spoof the document if need be just to test theory and discard possibility.

Answer (score 0):

"You often need access to attributes, properties, and **methods on the underlying element that are not directly exposed by HtmlElement, such as the SRC attribute on an IMG element** or the Submit method on a FORM. The GetAttribute and SetAttribute methods enable you to retrieve and alter any attribute or property on a specific element, while InvokeMember provides access to any methods not exposed in the managed Document Object Model (DOM). If your application has unmanaged code permission, you can also access unexposed properties and methods with the DomElement attribute." - 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.aspx

Think that suggests what the root issue is.  Honestly not sure how assigning the return value changes the htmlElement object accessors.  It seems like that is what is happening though.  Have not actually written any VB6 code in years, maybe someone else can actually explain why behaves as it does.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim image
```

that is wrong
image = WebBrowser1.Document.getElementById("image")

that is right
    set image = WebBrowser1.Document.getElementById("image")

```
dim image_src as String
image_src = image.src
```

Comment: It'd be helpful to explain what you've changed rather than letting everyone play spot the difference